# AngularJS: Dynamically add/remove wrapping directives to existing ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I need to be able to call a function of a directives controller, have it wrap an existing child directive in a new one while maintaining the now wrapped directive's state (both it's controller and all possible children) and otherwise modify the parent directive's template. This process also has to able to reversed.

[Quick and super dirty fiddle to show the idea](https://jsfiddle.net/w1L9q348/2/)

So the DOM starts as:

```
<split>
  <innerDirective></innerDirective>
</split>
```

When the split directive's controller's function is called, this should happen:

```
<split> // same outer parent
  <split> // new directive
    <innerDirective></innerDirective>// SAME innerDirective instance
  </split>
  <split>// new directive
    <innerDirective></innerDirective> //New innderDirective instance
  </split>
</split>
```

I originally used the .html function to set the split directives content, and used $compile service to reconstruct the DOM. This of course destroys the original innerDirective. Since it may be deep, it is not feasible to store it's data in the parent split and retrieve with a link function (although I tried).

I also tried using jquery's .wrap and .unwrap functions, which works, except the added tags aren't compiled as directives, so not really.

Is there a proper way to do this, or a way to compile just the outer tag added with the .wrap, and update the scope of the innerDirective to the new parent?

Thanks for any help and advice you may have!

Edit:
I have a controller along this lies, lets say set to control the split 'E' directive:

```
function SplitCtrl($scope, $compile){
  //stuff

  //First way, redefine html contents and recompile
  this.split1 = function(){
    //element has been linked to the directive's element
    $scope.element.html('<split></split><split></split>');
    $compile($scope.element.contents())($scope);
  };

  //Second way, jquery.wrap
  this.split2 = function(){
    $($scope.element).children('innerDirective').wrap('<split />');
    // then I need to instantiate the new split 
    // without reinstantiating now wrapped directive.
    // Adding second split is fine in this case, I can do that.
  };
};
```

The template is:

```
<innderDirective></innerDirective>
```

Comment: Unsure without the directive's code, but have you taken a look at `ng-transclude` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)? Otherwise I'm pretty sure that when the first split element compiles, everything inside of the opening and closing brace will be removed and replaced with the specified `template` or `templateURL`.

Comment: Transclude is for wrapping generic content with a directive. I need to be able to wrap an already instantiated directive in a new parent directive without reinstantiating it. The goal is to have this happen with a function of the original parent.

Comment: why is "without reinstantiating it" important to you? Transclusion does not require instantiation.  Still, I think you'll run into problems with infinite compilation. Do you see why?

Comment: I want to maintain the the data of the original. Infinite compilation is not a problem, that is why the template is an inner directive, not on the split directive. Essentially the split directive will either contain a single inner directive or two split directives. They only will contain two splits after the function is called. I am trying to not bloat the question with the specific complexities of the project. Transclusion won't work because the content is dynamic, this is all contained in higher level directives in the application.